# Issue with extra height under the names (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, height

How are U? I'm dealing with this problem: I have two columns with equal width, but in the right columns under the name, appear an extra height so the text are not equal aligned between both columns. I left here the link of the page that I'm working and the code is someone can help me...

---LINK: http://c2260485.ferozo.com/the-team/

```css
.tt-people {
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tt-people div {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.tt-people .flex-container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tt-people .flex-container section {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.tt-people h4 {
  font-family: fra-400;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #614C8A;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tt-people section p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #263238;
}

.tt-p2,
.tt-p3 {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.tt-p2 {
  font-family: rwe-700;
  color: #604B87;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tt-people div {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .tt-people br {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  .tt-people {
    padding: 80px 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    max-width: 1340px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .tt-people .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .tt-people-col2 {
    /* padding-left: 69px; */
  }
  .tt-people h4 {
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #614C8A;
    text-align: start;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .tt-people br {
    display: block;
  }
  .tt-people section p {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #263238;
    text-align: start;
  }
  .tt-people section {
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .tt-p2,
  .tt-p3 {
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: start;
  }
  .tt-p2 {
    font-family: rwe-700;
    color: #604B87;
    /* padding-right: 9%; */
  }
  .tt-p3 {
    /* padding-right: 10%; */
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container flex-nw tt-people">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <picture>
      <!-- <source srcset="" media="(min-width: )"> -->
      <img src="../wp-content/themes/CUSTOM/img/lee-tunstall.png" alt="MDN">
    </picture>
    <section>
      <h4>Lee Tunstall<br>PhD.</h4>
      <p class="tt-p1">SENIOR RESEARCH, WRITING AND<br>EDITING CONSULTANT</p>
    </section>

    <p class="tt-p2">Over the past 25 years, Lee Tunstall has crafted an eclectic career working with the public, private and non-profit sectors, while developing a unique understanding and perspective of the different environments.</p>
    <p class="tt-p3">This varied background makes her an effective consultant dealing with a variety of issues that have ranged from violence against women to seniors’ issues. With extensive and well-honed research skills, she communicates academic research to a more
      mainstream audience. Lee is a member of the Professional Writers Association of Canada, the Canadian Academy of Independent Scholars, and the Association of Independent Information Professionals. She is a sessional instructor in the Werklund School
      of Education at the University of Calgary, teaching online in the graduate research program. Lee holds a BA and MA from Carleton University and a PhD in History from the University of Cambridge.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container tt-people-col2">
    <picture>
      <!-- <source srcset="" media="(min-width: )"> -->
      <img src="../wp-content/themes/CUSTOM/img/lee-tunstall.png" alt="MDN">
    </picture>

    <section>
      <h4>Pamila Fonseka<br>BSc.</h4>
      <p class="tt-p1">SENIOR FUND DEVELOPMENT<br>CONSULTANT AND FACILITATOR</p>
    </section>

    <p class="tt-p2">Pamila has more than 10 years of experience raising funds for charities and motivating community support.</p>
    <p class="tt-p3">She is an established fundraiser in the non-profit sector, an ESG certification candidate, and a business proprietor. She has a proven record of planning, developing, and implementing strategic fundraising programs that have raised multiple million
      dollars for clients. She also develops standards, procedures, and processes for non-profits to meet industry and Canada Revenue Agency regulations and leads workshops for Board of Directors and senior leaders.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should really include a [example]. I have deleted my answer until you have done so, so I know for sure.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem very well!!! Sorry for my bad example, and thank you for let me know how to do it better next time! And thank you very much to read and response me!

Comment: Your example is fine, just make sure you include all CSS and the appropriate script sources that are required for it to run. i.e., Bootstrap CSS, Script Src's, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `align-self: flex-start;` to the second flex container that has the class `tt-people-col-2.` That fixes your alignment, then to clean it up a bit, you can add `gap: 20px;` on your parent flex-container since you are using `flex-wrap: nowrap;`. You will notice the spacing between the two `<p>` tags are off, since you are using Bootstrap you can just add some `mt`. However, I would nest the text in another div.

[image]